# Whenever I install a font using Font Book it copies a zero byte file into ~/Library/Fonts/

Tags: font

But it still works if I manually copy fonts there. These empty files have the following permissions: `--wxr-xr-x    1 mcb  staff        0  7 Okt  2011 Lekton-Regular.ttf`. What could be the problem here?

Comment: What Version of OS X are you using? Can you preview the actual font before installing with QuickLook and does it look okay?

Comment: 10.8.2 Mountain Lion, and the font can be viewed with QuickLook.

Comment: What are the permissions of the font(s) before you install them via Font Book?

Comment: The same issue was encountered here I think: http://www.dmertl.com/blog/?p=11

Comment: @HighlyIrregular Thanks for the follow-up. I have upgraded to Yosemite since then and haven’t encountered the problem again.